# Should I call ngOnInit() again in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and the question may sound stupid. Please bear with me.

I have defined my `ngOnInit` like:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.rowData = this.studentService.getStudents();//Make http calls to populate data
}
```

And in an event I call ngOnInit again as I need to reload the data:

```
onSomeEvent(){
 this.ngOnInit();
}
```

Is this OKAY? 
Or I should write the line to call http again if `ngOnInit()` is a costly method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this is not a good practice.

Better is to call some method from `ngOnInit` and reCall the same method when needed. Like this-

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.onLoad();
}

onLoad() {
this.rowData = this.studentService.getStudents();//Make http calls to populate data
}

onSomeEvent(){
 this.onLoad();
}
```

Comment: Does calling `ngOnInit` involve some DOM Manipulation or something costly?

Comment: Not if you call it yourself. BUT it makes the code less readable. ngOnInit has a purpose, INITIALISING the component. Using it for something else (in your case your purpose is "getListOfStudents") makes the code hard to understand. Other developers will not expect that ngOnInit is called multiple times. Easy problem in a small codebase. BIG problem when the code grows. Therefore it would be a good practice to have a method "getListOfStudents" and just call that method from ngOnInit()

Comment: ngOnInit called once the component is created, also as @JanRecker said it's not a good practice in terms of readabilty

Answer (score 2):

The better way to do it :

```
ngOnInit(){
this.loadData();
}

//load data

loadData(){
this.rowData = this.studentService.getStudents();
}

//on change event
ngOnChanges(){
this.loadData()
}

//capture data on other event
otherEvent(){
this.loadData()
}
```

Comment: Why to call method in `ngOnChanges`?

Comment: if there will be change form view or you are calling any selector that load conditionally ( in my case) than it will load data with different input. but its optional  if u d'ont have conditional view than no need. 

Thank you

Comment: This is massively wrong! ngOnChanges is called whenever one or more data-bound input properties change. This means **a lot**! You **do not** want to send http request that many times.

Comment: I am also saying same thing. ngOnChanges is called whenever one or more data-bound input properties change. but what if  data-bound input properties depends on http request/ response. 

Thankyou

Comment: You seriously never want to do that. Do a test: log in console counter of how many times ngOnChanges is called. For a massive page it might be 20 calls for every letter you put in input box. It would fire a http request 3000 times just for this comment.

Comment: you are not getting the point man there is scenario in which you are loading <selector></selector> conditionally than you need run ngOnChanges to get updated data.

Answer (score 1):

`ngOnInit` is lifecycle hook that is called after data-bound properties of a directive are initialized so first time it call by angualr it self  , so recalling this method will case alot of confusing to other and sign to poor code , so it better to break the code insde ngOnInit and called againg if need it.

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.refrechItems();
}

public refrechItems(): void {
  // magic things
}
```

you may cosider samething for all other lifecycle hooks

Answer (score 0):

Please do not do that! Angular has many different **Lifecycle hooks**

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks